# How to insert a new line break within the php code

Tags: php

```
<?php echo nl2br($valueu->getarea($rows['province'].'|'.$rows['city'].'|'.$rows['area'],' ')); ?></td>
```

how to put a line break in between city and area when outputted to a browser.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have, but it doesn't work. Like this <?php echo nl2br($valueu->getarea("$rows['province'].'|'.$rows['city'].'|'."\n"$rows['area'],' '")); ?></td> or <?php echo nl2br($valueu->getarea("$rows['province'].'|'.$rows['city'].'|'.\n$rows['area'],' '")); ?></td>

Comment: The second \n is without the ""

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: yes, error reportingno errors in the php logs

Comment: but are gettin a white screen.

Comment: I might add that getarea is a function where it retrieves the name of the respective fields, if it matters.

Comment: So you've tried both of the samples? Like `\n` and `"\n"`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n`. Just add it with the sting like this  `I."\n" like pie`.

You can also use `nl2br` like this `echo nl2br("One line.\nAnother line.");`

Comment: Doesn't the expression go like "In like Flynn"? lol but easy as pie. Mmm... pie.

Answer (score 1):

Try double quote `"\n"`.

If you use single quote `'\n'`, PHP will just interpret as a literal `\n`, but within double quote, it will parse it as an escape sequence (newline character) and echo it. More about strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

```
echo nl2br('Hello \n world');
// -> Hello \n world

echo nl2br("Hello \n world");
// -> Hello <br /> world
```

Answer (score 0):

In a browser, you may need to use `"<br/>"` instead of a newline `"\n"`.

```
echo($valueu->getarea($rows['province'].'|'.$rows['city'].'<br />'.$rows['area'],' '));
```

Something like that?

Comment: True, but OP is using `nl2br()`

Comment: I didn't read closely enough - all I "read" was "line break" and "browser". Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: You're welcome. However, your answer would also work, if the OP wasn't using that function.